# tableview - unrecognized selector didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have been having an issue with my app crashing on selecting something in the tableView. This is not 100% reproducible, but it happens relatively often.

What happens is inside my EventListViewController class (a subclass of UITableViewController), I overwrite the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function because I am using a search bar in this class as well, and I want it to only select when you are not searching.

The code looks like this:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(!searching)
        [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

However, when it crashes, I break on exception and this is the message I get, on the line that calls the super function:

```
[EventListViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa648e50
```

I printed out some stuff on the debugger and it all looks fine to me:

```
(lldb) po 0xa648e50
(int) $1 = 174362192 <EventListViewController: 0xa648e50>

(lldb) po self
(EventListViewController *) $2 = 0x0a648e50 <EventListViewController: 0xa648e50>

(lldb) po tableView
(UITableView *) $3 = 0x070fd400 <UITableView: 0x70fd400; frame = (0 0; 320 367); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x6e46750>; contentOffset: {-0, -0}>

(lldb) po indexPath
(NSIndexPath *) $4 = 0x06e8caf0 <NSIndexPath 0x6e8caf0> 2 indexes [1, 1]
```

(The tableView has 2 sections,and the second section has 2 entries)

Anyone have any Idea what is happening? let me know if you need any more information.

Note: after more investigation I have found that this is 100 % reproducible with the following steps:
1: load the app, and click on either of the two entries.
2: Go back to the tableView controller
3: tap BELOW both of the entries, in the white space where there shouldn't be a cell
The app will crash, but notice that the indexPath doesn't say its trying to select a cell that is outside the bounds of the tableView, just that the tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath method doesn't exist

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The call to `super` in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is unnecessary.  If I remember correctly, `UITableViewController` does not provide a default implementation of that method.  Thus, your call to super results in a crash.

Comment: So perhaps, then, the prudent thing to do is wrap it in `if([super respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)]) {...}`, just in case the code gets moved somewhere that *does* inherit from an implementor.

Comment: Wow, that was a lot simpler than I thought. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ctrahey sadly, this doesn't work. [super respondsToSelector:@selector(tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)] returns true. Probably because super implements the protocol, but not the optional method.

Comment: I guess `didSelect...` is an `@optional` method of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol, then? This is funny, because in Swift, the stub is still marked as `override` when you subclass...