# Is it acceptable to call super tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath: in a custom subclass?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a custom `UITableviewViewController` class called SuperTableVC. I also have a subclass of SuperTableVC called SubTableVC that I would like to just add one more method call within `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Can I (should I) do the following in SubTableVC?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   [self doSomethingExtra];    

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Why not? It's basic class inheritance logic.

Comment: Are you sure @sha? check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11820688/3100991

Comment: The question was not about default table view implementation.