# Unrecognized selector tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: when I overload the method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, unrecognized-selector

Ok here's a weird one. I have a `UITableViewController`-derived class called `ProfileViewController` that is instantiated from a storyboard with static table content. The storyboard view controller's class is set to `ProfileViewController`. Inside `ProfileViewController` I override `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` with the intention of intercepting a specific cell selection, passing the call onto `[super tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]` if it's not the cell I'm looking for.

When I select a cell the first time, my override is called and it works fine. However the *second* cell I select causes the app to crash with an unrecognized selector exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ProfileViewController
>   tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x14e9c4d0'

But `ProfileViewController` definitely has that selector!

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Even stranger, if I comment out my overload, cell selection works without a hitch. So my question is why does *defining* `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` cause an unrecognized selector on the *second* cell selection? I'm stumped!

Comment: I dont think delegate callbacks should ever be passet to super. Should they?

Comment: @Eyeball Generally no, but in the case of a `UITableViewController`, the class is its own delegate and it has built-in handling of table view delegate methods.

Comment: See the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820646/tableview-unrecognized-selector-didselectrowatindexpath

Comment: `UITableViewController` does not have the delegate methods so calling `[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];` won't work.

Comment: D'oh, thanks. I just assumed it would provide an implementation for that since it seems to for most other table view methods. Still, it's strange it would work the first time, and also strange that the exception doesn't say `[UITableViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]`.

Comment: Ah, it actually *doesn't* work the first time, but there is a delay before it actually crashes.